# .NET MAUI Example Hamburger Menu (NON Shell)?

Tags: maui

Is it possible to create a hamburger menu for a page without using shell? We would like to have a menu with nothing but menu items and not to be used for navigation.

To add more:

I know this piece of XAML can be assigned to a control but could be assigned to a page as "hamburger menu"?

```
    <FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
    <MenuFlyout>
        <MenuFlyoutItem 
            Text="Lookup Items"
            Clicked="MenuFlyoutItem_Clicked"
            CommandParameter="Lookup"
            />

        <MenuFlyoutItem 
            Text="Scanned Items"
            Clicked="MenuFlyoutItem_Clicked"
            CommandParameter="Scanned"
            />
    </MenuFlyout>
</FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you basically want a popup, with stack layout full with labels? And this popup to show on button click, that has icon of hamburger? Yes, you can totally do it. It makes very little sense, but you can do it.

Comment: @H.A.H. Not really. I edited and added a bit more info. Looking to build a hamburger menu that is NOT a part of the shell navigation. I just want a context menu with menu items only that is assigned to a hamburger menu at the top left of a page.

Comment: If you want to do something custom, then don't use Shell's features for that part of it. Research various features of Maui, and build your own. You can put whatever you want into a ContentView or ContentPage. Use your own image for the icon. etc. Get as far as you can. If you get stuck, then make a new question, with your code, and a specific detail that you are stuck on.

Comment: @BitWiseByteDumb If I understand you correctly, you want something like side drawer? Most 3rd party controls have such control. You can check the code behind and "get some ideas". They are suspiciously similar, so the first one will do. (After all they have been "getting ideas" from each other for the last 10 years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like what I needed was the ToolbarItems part of a page. Shell is not needed (But can be used in conjunction with).
Add this to your page in XAML or code behind (Example in XAML):

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem
        StyleId="Item1"
        Order="Secondary"
        Text="Item 1"
        />
    <ToolbarItem
        StyleId="Item2"
        Order="Secondary"
        Text="Item 2"
        />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Setting an item as secondary will automatically put the item to a three-dot/hamburger menu which appears at the top right.

Appearance being like:

[image]

[image]

These items are easily accessible and can be modified with a Page's ToolbarItems collection.

Such as:

LoginPage.ToolbarItems.Clear();

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

The answer by the OP works in any page that has been **navigated to**. If you wanted this menu in your *first* (root) page, you would need to load said first page as a `NavigationPage` in `App.xaml.cs`, i.e., with: `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());`