# Shell FlyoutItem menu outside of MainPage.xaml

Tags: .net, mobile, maui

I am playing with Monkey Finder tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuNLR_NJv8U. There is a DetailsPage.xaml that is navigated to using

```
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync( nameof( DetailsPage ), true, new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"Monkey", monkey }
        } );
```

I'm able to add a Flyout Menu to the MainPage.xaml using AppShell.xaml. How do I add Flyout Menu for a ContentPage other than MainPage.xaml that uses Shell?

```
    <FlyoutItem Title="Dashboard"
        FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <ShellContent Title="Dashboard"
              ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:MainPage}"
              Route="MainPage"
              Icon="dotnet_bot.svg" />

    <ShellContent Title="Profile"
              ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:ProfilePage}"
              Route="ProfilePage"
              Icon="dotnet_bot.svg" />
    <ShellContent Title="Billing"
              ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:BillingPage}"
              Route="BillingPage"
              Icon="dotnet_bot.svg" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I add Flyout Menu for a ContentPage other than MainPage.xaml
> that uses Shell?

Potentially, there're mainly two ways to achieve this:

#1: Use [FlyoutPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.flyoutpage).

As the flyout menu is a navigation panel that slides out from the side of the screen, providing quick access to frequently used features or settings.

The following example shows the definition of the `FlyoutMenuPage` object, which is of type [ContentPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.contentpage):

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlyoutPageNavigation"
             x:Class="FlyoutPageNavigation.FlyoutMenuPage"
             Padding="0,40,0,0"
             IconImageSource="hamburger.png"
             Title="Personal Organiser">
    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                    x:FieldModifier="public"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:FlyoutPageItem}">
                <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="Contacts"
                                      IconSource="contacts.png"
                                      TargetType="{x:Type local:ContactsPage}" />
                <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="TodoList"
                                      IconSource="todo.png"
                                      TargetType="{x:Type local:TodoListPage}" />
                <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="Reminders"
                                      IconSource="reminders.png"
                                      TargetType="{x:Type local:ReminderPage}" />
            </x:Array>
        </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="5,10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Margin="20,0"
                           Text="{Binding Title}"
                           FontSize="20"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

For more details, you can refer to [Create a FlyoutPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/flyoutpage?view=net-maui-8.0#create-a-flyoutpage)

#2: Make the controls from scratch that mimic the default functionality of the Shell `FlyoutItem` menu. You can refer to this excellent answered thread:[Can a Flyoutwindow/hamburger menu be implemented outside of the shell in .NET MAUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77580890). And don't forget to set the default starting page as you are not using the Shell.

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
  //MainPage = new AppShell();
    MainPage = new MainPage();
}
```

**Output:**

[image]